# Problema Collapse acordion Con ajax

Tags: ajax, accordion

Estoy tratando de cargar el contenido de una tabla que cuenta con información dentro de un collapse Accordion, pero me carga el contenido del accordion al lado de la tabla y no oculto como debería:

Mi ajax:

```
        // Gestión de RMA Dinámica
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + 'index.php/welcome/getGestionRMA',
            dataType: "json",
            data:{

            },
            success:function(e){

                $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").html(" ");

                for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ )
                {
                    console.log(e[i]);
                    var tr  = "<tr data-rma='" + e[i]['rmaId'] + "'>";
                    var td1 = "<td>" + e[i]['reference'] + "</td>";
                    var td2 = "<td>" + e[i]['name'] + "</td>";
                    var td3 = "<td>" + e[i]['date'].split("-").reverse().join("/") + " (" + e[i]['time'] + ")</td>";   
                    var td4 = "<td>" + e[i]['firstName'] + " " + e[i]['lastName'] + "</td>";   

                    var acciones = e[i]['action'].split(",");

                    if( (acciones.length -1) == 1)
                    {
                        var td5 = "<td><a data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#acordeon" + e[i]['rmaId'] + "' class='link-underlined link-blue accordion-toggle'>" + (acciones.length -1)  + " acción </a></td>";
                    } else {
                        var td5 = "<td><a data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#acordeon" + e[i]['rmaId'] + "' class='link-underlined link-blue accordion-toggle'>" + (acciones.length -1)  + " acciones </a></td>";

                    }
                    var td6 = "<td class='icono-rma-remove fa fa-times' data-popout='true'></td>";
                    var td7 = "<td class='icono-equipo-edit fa fa-pencil'></td>";
                    var tr2 = "</tr>";

                    var tr3 = "<tr class='hijo'>";
                    var td8 = "<td colspan='12' class='hiddenRow'>";
                    var div1 = "<div class='accordian-body collapse margin-bottom-20' id='acordeon" + e[i]['rmaId'] +"'>";

                    $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+tr2);

                    $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append("<tr class='hijo'>");
                    $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append("<td colspan='12' class='hiddenRow'>");
                    $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append("<div class='accordian-body collapse margin-bottom-20' id='acordeon" + e[i]['rmaId'] +"'></div>");

                    for (var a = 0; a < acciones.length -1 ; a++)
                    {  

                        $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append("<div class='tituloSubcampoRma margin-top-20 margin-horizontal-20'>" + acciones[a] + "</div>");
                    }

                    $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append("</td>");
                    $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append("</tr>");
                }

            },
            error:function(e){

            }
        });
```

Mi acordeon:

```
      <tr class="hijo">
         <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
             <div class="accordian-body collapse margin-bottom-20" id="acordeon1">
             <div class="tituloSubcampoRma margin-top-20 margin-horizontal-20">1 - Ajuste de la propela</div>
             <div class="textoSubcampoRma margin-top-5 margin-horizontal-20">Ajuste y engrase de la propela para un mejor funcionamiento.</div>
             <div class="tituloSubcampoRma margin-top-20 margin-horizontal-20">2 - Cambio de pieza</div>
             <div class="textoSubcampoRma margin-top-5 margin-horizontal-20">Se sustituyo el brazo del rotor principal por uno nuevo. Referencia de recambio 0012345</div>
             </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

¿Alguien me puede indicar donde está mi error?

Comment: puedes agregar el código de tu accordion en el html?

Comment: ya está editada la pregunta con el código del acordeon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: base_url + 'index.php/welcome/getGestionRMA',
      dataType: "json",
      data:{
      },
      success:function(e){
        $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").html(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ )
        {
           var tr  = "<tr data-rma='" + e[i]['rmaId'] + "'>";
           var td1 = "<td>" + e[i]['reference'] + "</td>";
           var td2 = "<td>" + e[i]['name'] + "</td>";
           var td3 = "<td>" + e[i]['date'].split("-").reverse().join("/") + " (" + e[i]['time'] + ")</td>";   
           var td4 = "<td>" + e[i]['firstName'] + " " + e[i]['lastName'] + "</td>";   

           var acciones    = e[i]['action'].split(",");
           var descripcion = e[i]['description'].split(",");

           if( (acciones.length -1) == 1)
           {
              var td5 = "<td><a data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#acordeon" + e[i]['rmaId'] + "' class='link-underlined link-blue accordion-toggle'>" + (acciones.length -1)  + " acción </a></td>";
           } else {
              var td5 = "<td><a data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#acordeon" + e[i]['rmaId'] + "' class='link-underlined link-blue accordion-toggle'>" + (acciones.length -1)  + " acciones </a></td>";

           }
           var td6 = "<td class='icono-rma-remove fa fa-times' data-popout='true'></td>";
           var td7 = "<td class='icono-equipo-edit fa fa-pencil'></td>";

           var tr2 = "<tr class='hijo'>";
           var td8 = "<td colspan='12' class='hiddenRow'>";
           var div1 = "<div class='accordian-body collapse margin-bottom-20' id='acordeon" + e[i]['rmaId'] +"'>";

           var contenido = "";
           var contador = 1;
           for (var a = 0; a < acciones.length -1 ; a++)
           {  

               var contenido = contenido + "<div class='tituloSubcampoRma margin-top-20 margin-horizontal-20'>" + contador + "-" + acciones[a] + "</div>";
               var contenido = contenido + "<div class='textoSubcampoRma margin-top-5 margin-horizontal-20'>" + descripcion[a] + "</div>";
               contador++;
           }

           $(".cuerpo-tabla-rma").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+tr2+td8+div1+contenido);
       }

    },
    error:function(e){
    }
```

});